# Attaching an entity of type "" failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have inherited some rather large code after a fellow employee left the company. Unfortunately the program broke the day after he left. Could anyone point me where to look with the following error?

> Attaching an entity of type 'MasT.DB.jobqueue' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate. at
>
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.VerifyRootForAdd(Boolean doAttach, String entitySetName, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntityEntry existingEntry, EntitySet& entitySet, Boolean& isNoOperation) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Attach>b__9() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity) at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Attach(TEntity entity) at DT.ValidatorCore.JobQueue.MasTJobQueueMySql.<>c.b__23_7(jobqueue jq) at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action) at DT.ValidatorCore.JobQueue.MasTJobQueueMySql.MaintainJobQueue() at DT.ValidatorCore.JobQueue.MasTJobQueueMySql.TakeJobsQueue(Boolean includeCompleted) at DT.ValidatorCore.JobQueue.MasTJobQueue.DoWork(String date, Boolean testRun, Int32 runId) at DT.ValidatorCore.Commands.TriggerCommand.QueueCommand.Process(CmdTrigger`1 trigger) at DT.Common.Commands.BaseCommand`1.TriggerSubCommand(CmdTrigger`1 trigger) at DT.Common.Commands.Command`1.Process(CmdTrigger`1 trigger) at DT.Common.Commands.CommandMgr`1.Execute(CmdTrigger`1 trigger, BaseCommand`1 cmd, Boolean silentFail)

I am very confused as this does not happen when running in debug, only when the program is running on the production server. While they connect to two separate databases, these are identical.

Initially I was only asked to update certain parts of the code so this is a big jump!

I am fairly certain the issue is with the `DT.ValidatorCore.JobQueue.MasTJobQueueMySql.MaintainJobQueue`, but I have very limited knowledge of entity framework

```
    protected void MaintainJobQueue()
    {
        if (_jobQueueUnitOfWork != null)
            _jobQueueUnitOfWork.Dispose();

        _jobQueueUnitOfWork = new JobQueueUnitOfWork();

        List<jobqueue> tempList = _jobQueueUnitOfWork.JobQueueRepository.GetAll();

        if (tempList == null)
            return;

        tempList.RemoveAll(jqItem => jqItem == null);
        tempList.RemoveAll(jqItem => jqItem.packageinfo == null);
        tempList.RemoveAll(jqItem => jqItem.packageinfo.pkg_content_id == null);

        if (!tempList.Any())
            return;

        var tempList2 = tempList.GroupBy(g => g.packageinfo.pkg_content_id + g.packageinfo.pkg_master_version + g.packageinfo.app_version).Select(x => x.ToList().OrderByDescending(m => m.packageinfo.app_revision).First()).ToList();

        tempList.RemoveAll(i => tempList2.Contains(i));
        tempList.ForEach(jq => context.jobqueue.Attach(jq));


        var pkgInfoRemovals = tempList.Select(i => i.packageinfo);
        _jobQueueUnitOfWork.PackageInfoRepository.DeleteRange(pkgInfoRemovals);

        var submissionpathRemovals = tempList.Select(i => i.submissionpath);
        context.submissionpath.RemoveRange(submissionpathRemovals);
        _jobQueueUnitOfWork.SubmissionPathRepository.DeleteRange(submissionpathRemovals);


        _jobQueueUnitOfWork.JobQueueRepository.DeleteRange(tempList);
    }

    protected override void SaveChanges()
    {
        _jobQueueUnitOfWork.Save();
    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: It's hard to tell by only seeing the exception and no code, but it's as it says, your table has a unique key constraint where every value must be unique and you're trying to add a value with a duplicate key. Can you confirm if the row(s) being added are new or modified?

Comment: The rows are added initially at the start of each day & then updated once later on. I created a blank database and it will work for one day correctly & then error out the following morning

Comment: So...which bit does it fail on, the adding or the updating?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the comment as you responded - "I created a blank database and it will work for one day correctly & then error out the following morning"

Comment: That means nothing to me, I don't know what it does one day from the next. I assume it fails when the rows are updated? How are you retrieving and then modifying the rows in the database? It sounds like they become detached and so EF tries to insert rather than update. It's hard to guess unless you show the code that throws the exception.

Comment: Added the method which I think is causing the error to the main comment

Comment: Is this class some kind of wrapper around EF? I don't recognise some of the method calls. What does the `.GetAll();` method look like? A guess says you need to mark these entries as modified after attaching so `tempList.ForEach( jq => { context.jobqueue.Attach(jq); context.Entry(jq).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; });`

Comment: Hey Equalsk, the code you provided has worked so far..its created new database entry's for today and updated them throughout! (without having to wipe the db) -

If it runs tomorrow morning then all should be in the clear, but I won't be able to see the results until Monday. I'll post the result back here. Thanks :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be sure as the code you've shared appears to be a wrapper built around Entity Framework and so obscures away some of the necessary detail but an educated guess says that you're dealing with `Detached Entities`.

The keyword to search for is `DbContext` (Database Context).

If you use Entity Framework (EF) to fetch some data from your database this data remains attached to the database or `DbContext`, this is an `attached entity`.
Any changes made to the data are now automatically tracked by EF so when you call `SaveChanges()` it knows to `UPDATE` the existing data.

In your case I suspect that `_jobQueueUnitOfWork.JobQueueRepository.GetAll();` fetches data from somewhere else such as a Web API. As this data was created outside of `DbContext` then EF can't possibly know what state it's in, this is a `detached entity`.
The solution is to simply tell EF what state the data is in, in your case it's modified and requires an `UPDATE` over an `INSERT`.

```
tempList.ForEach(jq => 
{ 
    context.jobqueue.Attach(jq); // Attach to `DbContext`
    context.Entry(jq).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; // Modified
});
```

If you search for Entity Framework articles relating to `dbcontext`, `change tracking` and `attached/detached entities` it should answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate, it's been working since Friday! i'll dig into your suggestions for Entity Framework its defiantly something i'll need to know about in the coming months :)

Comment: No problem, glad it works. It's usually polite to accept the answer that worked by clicking the green arrow on the left ;-)

Comment: done! :) need some reputation before I can publicly up-vote though!

Comment: Well for what it's worth I always upvote questions that I answer so enjoy your 7 rep from me ;-)